# Where Laravel store user session

Tags: laravel, session, cookies, session-cookies

After creating authentication system for user using **Laravel 5*** I am wondering where Laravel store `user session`?
In other words Laravel store `user session` in a cookie(client side) or server side?
And if in cookie so it hash that session right? and this is not secured right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel stores it on server side. You can choose where to store it: files, DB, Redis etc.

> Laravel ships with a variety of session backends that are accessed through an expressive, unified API. Support for popular backends such as Memcached, Redis, and databases is included out of the box.

You may learn more about sessions [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session).